# Window handle doesn't save correctly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013, hwnd

I don't really get how to use HWND in c++.
I want to press a button and it should start a thread with a code running.
But I never receive the command for button click in an other callback.
So I did some debugging and it seems like that _wndInstance->GetWndHWND() returns something not valid. The method returns a private field which has it stored.

If you look a case WM_CREATE, the window content added will not show up with _wndInstance->GetWndHWND(). But if I just use hwnd from the parameters, it does work. But how is that possible if my first test-check validates that they are the same??

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (_wndInstance->GetWndHWND() == hwnd)
    cout << "same" << endl; // Code is getting here!

switch (msg)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
case WM_CREATE:
{
    _wndInstance->CreateWndContent(_wndInstance->GetWndHWND()); // not working, but hwnd is!
}
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
```

}

EDIT:

_wndInstance is an instance of a mainwindow class I wrote.
Part of mainWindow header:

```
private:
HWND _wndHwnd;

public:
HWND GetWndHWND();
```

MainWindow cpp:

```
     HWND MainWindow::GetWndHWND()
     {
        return _wndHwnd;
     }
```

_wndHwnd is set in a private method which creates the window:

```
_wndHwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "\"Xbox controller on WINDOWS\" Manager",
    WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, // no maximize box
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 450, 370,
    NULL, NULL, hinstance, NULL);
if (_wndHwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return;
}

ShowWindow(_wndHwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(_wndHwnd);
```

Comment: What's the code that sets the value returned by `GetWndHWND()`?

Comment: I edited it in the post.
I'm also using VS 2013 with the default compiler.

Comment: Make an MCVE and post that, together with a clear problem description

Comment: That approach can't work.  The first calls to the Window procedure occur *before* CreateWindowEx returns, i.e., before you've initialized _wndHwnd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WM_CREATE` is sent before `CreateWindowEx()` returns, and thus before your assignment happens. You will need to restructure your code so that the `HWND` is only used after it is assigned to `_wndHwnd`.

If you don't need to do anything between `WM_CREATE` and the beginning of the message loop, you can just drop your `WM_CREATE` handler. That depends on how your code will work in the future.

But a safer approach would be to assign `_wndHwnd` in your `WM_CREATE` handler (or even `WM_NCCREATE`), since you have it available as the `hwnd` parameter to your window procedure, and it would handle other messages sent between the window creation and the variable assignment. You can even pass `_wndInstance` as the last parameter to `CreateWindowEx()` and access it from `WM_CREATE`; see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/03/10496248.aspx) for details.